# Python: Converting from binary to String

Tags: python, python-2.x

In Python, I have been able to take in a string of 32 bits, and convert this into a binary number with the following code:

```
def doConvert(string):
    binary = 0
    for letter in string:
        binary <<= 8
        binary += ord(letter)

    return binary
```

So for the string, `'abcd'`, this method will return the correct value of 1633837924, however I cannot figure out how to do the opposite; take in a 32 bit binary number and convert this to a string.

If someone could help, I would appreciate the help!

Comment: @shuttle87 I'm using Python2

Comment: Is it always a 32bit integer?

Comment: yeah always a 32bit string being converted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are always dealing with a 32 bit integer you can use the [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) module to do this:

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.pack(">I", 1633837924)
'abcd'
```

Just make sure that you are using the same [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) to both pack and unpack otherwise you will get results that are in the wrong order, for example:

```
>>> struct.pack("<I", 1633837924)
'dcba'
```

Comment: Thanks, this works really well! What does the argument, ">I" do? I can't find a reasonable explanation in the docs.

Comment: The `I` says that it is an unsigned integer. The `>` says that it is in [big-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Big-endian) format.

Comment: `>>> help(struct)`

    The optional first format char indicates byte order, size and alignment:
      @: native order, size & alignment (default)
      =: native order, std. size & alignment
      <: little-endian, std. size & alignment
      >: big-endian, std. size & alignment
      !: same as >

Comment: `help(struct)` is a good idea! Also the [struct documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment) has a table with the possible formats.